# Where can i find the typescript type declarations for mysql2?

Tags: typescript, express, mysql2

So, I'm connecting to a MySQL db using the mysql2 module (with pools and async/await) and I handle possible errors with a try catch block, when the catch gets the error typescript says it is unknown

P.S: some code is in spanish

```
  register = async (req: Request, res:Response) => {
    const usuario: RegistroUsuario = req.body

    usuario.nombres = this.#convertirACamelCase(usuario.nombres)
    usuario.apellidos = this.#convertirACamelCase(usuario.apellidos)
    usuario.contrasena = this.#generarContrasena({ nombres: usuario.nombres, apellidos: usuario.apellidos, documento: usuario.documento })

    try {
      await pool.query('CALL sp_registro_usuario(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
        [usuario.documento, usuario.nombres, usuario.apellidos, usuario.usuario, usuario.contrasena,
          1, usuario.idRol])
      return res.json(usuario)
    } catch (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
      return res.status(500).json({ mensaje: 'paila no dio jaja' })
    }
  }
```

I looked at the docs, asked chatGPT and searched online for more info but found nothing. Also looked for .d.ts files in the github repo but didn't find anything